# jQuery - is there better syntax than "parent().parent().parent()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm doing some quite rudimentary jQuery stuff, getting started really, and I'm frequently navigating up the dom by doing things like

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('hello');
```

I was just wondering if there's a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), which returns all ancestor elements in turn. If you want to stop traversing at a particular level, use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to filter the resulting collection. For example, to get the grandparent:

```
// 0 = parent, 1 = parent of parent, etc.
$(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('hello');
```

If you want to go upwards through the tree and stop not at a particular level, but at a particular selector match, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead, e.g.:

```
$(this).closest("table").addClass('hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method, which returns the first element that matches the given selector in the ancestor chain.

```
$(this).closest(SELECTOR_OF_THE_PARENT).addClass('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <strong>Hi there</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

You could just use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get the `div` element:

```
$("strong").parents("div").addClass("hello");
```

Simply replace `"strong"` with `this` and you can use a selector to find a specific parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your after `.parents()` or `.closest()` -- the latter being the most efficient, as it stops progressing up the DOM once it matches the closest selector.

Answer (score 0):

*"I was just wondering if there's a nicer way to do this?"*

It's definitely a great idea to be intimately familiar with jQuery's selection and traversal methods.

However, if in the future you find yourself overwhelmed by traversal and discover:

1. That your "data model" is actually contained in your DOM
2. Maintaining and changing applications of this nature is very painful

...it might be time to consider a formal [model](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)-[view](http://blog.sproutcore.com/sproutcore-2-0-beta-1-released/) [approach](http://javascriptmvc.com/).